# Google recaptcha style problem, solve with css or javascript?

Tags: css, recaptcha

I'm using recaptcha v.2 for my website, but for some reason, it brakes the layout because it won't size the space of the parent box (div).

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey' : 'mysitekey'
        });
    };
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
async defer>
```

and html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="recaptcha" required=""></div>
</div>
```

The form-group is already max-width: 100%; but for some reason, the recaptcha doesn't follow that rule:

Here's an example:

https://careercollege.sehc.com/vancouver/programs/hca-diploma-program/.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this sometimes:

```
#recaptcha {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: solid 1px lightgray;
}
```

Comment: It does do that.